# Twilio: how to warn users before call ends aggressively with time limited calls?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

So here what i have, when a user A calls my Twilio number, the call is forwarded towards another user B number through a Twiml response which dials user B number. I have done a time limit for any calls which is 5 minutes, but i would like to prevent the two users when there is only 1 minute left that time is nearly up and avoid cutting out aggressively the call.

Any one has an idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 4):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You could have the users actually call into a [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference) ([generating a call to user B](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) when user A calls and enters the conference) and then start a timer for 4 minutes on your server. When the timer is done you can then check if the conference is still live (by [calling the REST API and checking the conference status](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/conference#instance-properties)) and if it is dial one more caller into the conference.

That caller could be a [recorded message that you play with `<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) or a message to be read out with [text to speech using `<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) that lets the callers know that there's only one minute left.

For example:

```
<Response>
  <Say voice="alice">Warning. There is only one minute of calling time left.</Say>
  <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

**Update**

This is now better done with announcements that can be played into conferences. Check out the blog post here with details on [how to announce messages into a conference](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/07/twilio-conference-now-supports-announcements.html).

Comment: Thanks philnash ! This might be very helpful :-)

Comment: I just updated this answer a bit, you no longer need to dial in a bot to make an announcement, check out [how to make announcements with the conference API instead](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/07/twilio-conference-now-supports-announcements.html).

Comment: @philnash - is there any way to modify calls made to the REST API (via python sdk)?  I find that calls timeout at a max of 1 Hr 18 Mins 18 Secs.  It's very consistent, leading me to think it's an upper limit of the REST API.

I can't just use TWIML for this as I need to dial, wait on an interaction, which might take a long time, and then connect two callers.  It's the waiting on one side that takes the majority of the time, and times out if it takes more than 1 Hr 18 Mins 18 Secs.

Comment: Hi @snakesNbronies, the timeout at 1 hour 18 minutes and 18 seconds seems like something is going wrong as there is no published limit that I know of around that. I recommend you [get in touch with Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) with a description of what you're doing and some example call sids where this happened and they might be able to help.